# android: Custom view not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble creating a custom view.

If my understanding is correct, i wish for a compound view where ui elements like Switch can be incorporated within a custom view. An example of intention of this will be a modal view that displays a series of switches with a save & back button with relative actions, in context to an in-app form purpose.

In other examples/questions people have mentioned `this.addView(View childView)` however when i try to use this function i get an unresolved symbol error from android studio. When executed, the app displays blank.

```
public class NewView extends View {
private Switch switchOne;
private Switch switchTwo;

public NewView(Context context){
    super(context);
    init(null, 0);
}

public NewView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context);
    init(attrs, 0);
}

public NewView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context);
    init(attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    //LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customview, (ViewGroup) this.getParent(), true); //First attempted this approach
    ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customview, (ViewGroup) this.getParent()); //then attempted this approach

    this.switchOne = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.firstSwitch);
    this.switchTwo = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.secondSwitch);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

customview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainView">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstSwitch"/>
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondSwitch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.simonaddicott.customviewone.NewView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/myNewView"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your component extend ViewGroup instead of View ?

Comment: instead of getting context `(Activity) getContext()` better to use locar variable from constructor.

Comment: @2Dee - i'm not sure, should it? ive come from an iOS cocoa background so assumed that a custom view would natrually extend View.

Comment: ViewGroup is a subclass of View which is designed to have View children and should be the bases of any 'Compound' custom view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend from ViewGroup, override onLayout and provide an implementation. Alternatively, since you seem to just want the switches laid out vertically, just extend from LinearLayout to reuse its layout rules and set the orientation for your `NewView` in the activity_main.xml, or in code if you want to override the xml setting and enforce the vertical layout.

Replace the root `LinearLayout` in customview.xml with a `merge`.

When inflating, use `this` and not `this.getParent()` as the second parameter

Comment: I found (https://github.com/devunwired/custom-view-examples) this example helped my understanding dramatically combined with your answer. much appreciated